Does a convict in a U.S. prison have the status of a slave?
Both the U.S. convict and the person sold into slavery experience a downgrade in status at the hands of the court.
Does this similarity cause a person in a U.S. prison to be halachically a slave?
Does it matter if the person is Jewish? Does it matter if they are forced at gunpoint to work, strongly encouraged to work so they can access amenities, prison work is voluntary and does not vastly improve conditions?

Notably, prison slavery is legal in the usa https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thirteenth_Amendment_to_the_United_States_Constitution#Penal_labor_exemption

With respect to what?

If I'm the warden, can I assign him pointless labor (e.g. the crank). When he is released, do I have to permit him to live near me? I e. Is a Jewish landlord allowed to discriminate based on ex con status? Does a Jewish warden have to parole him if he loses an eye doing prison work?

Why would it give someone slave status in Halacha. If the government were to mandate civil service would that make people slaves? Does a prison warden own anyone?
